# How to configure httpd or php-fpm service which version of php to use on Red Hat 7

Tags: php, redhat, php-fpm, httpd

I'm new to Red Hat, because of a problem described here:[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008849/moving-laravel-project-from-windows-to-redhat-7-class-pdo-not-found/48010570#48010570) I end up with 2 instalation of php 7.1.

First I've installed rh-php71 package from Red Hat repo, because I don't have pdo drivers for Microsoft SQL I instaled also php7.1 from Remi repo.

Ok, now I want to instruct httpd24 to use the one from remi (located in /opt/remi/php71).

**The actual php work in php-fpm mode**

How do I achieve that?

Do I have to config something on php-fm service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I've installed rh-php71 package from Red Hat repo, because I
>   don't have pdo drivers for Microsoft SQL I instaled also php7.1 from
>   Remi repo.

Indeed, Remi repository provides [much more extensions](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status) than any other sources.

> So, php-fpm service for rh-php71 was rh-php71-php-fpm so I disabled it
>   and install php71-php-fpm from Remi and now it's working :)

Yes, that is the way.

> I think I could configure rh-php71-php-fm to work with the php stack
>   from remi repo

No, you cannot.

For memory, everything is described in [PHP Configuration tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/).

Answer (score 0):

So, php-fpm service for rh-php71 was rh-php71-php-fpm so I disabled it and install php71-php-fpm from Remi and now it's working :)

I think I could configure rh-php71-php-fm to work with the php stack from remi repo but I don't know from where?